# ubuntu 20.04 rtl8723 -- bluetooth not working

Tags: bluetooth, 20.04

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on atom-based tablet ACER Aspire Switch 10. And bluetooth does not work. In fact it looks like ubuntu does not recognize bluetooth HW at all. But the system does have bluetooth module which under windows is recognized as RTK8723 (ACPI\RTK8723\some-id)

I googled around and found out that at least for five last years people manage to bring 8723 HW to work under linux. But the solutions involve compile/install some module(s). I could go this way, but really have a doubt about duplicating some mechanism that is present in the distribution already and which I just need to switch on, but do not know how to do it.

What would you suggest me to do?

Details:

```
$ lsb_release -d
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
$ uname -vr
5.4.0-26-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 20 16:58:30 UTC 2020
$ dmesg | grep -i 8723
[    8.087918] r8723bs: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    8.088914] r8723bs: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
[    8.092667] RTL8723BS: module init start
[    8.092671] RTL8723BS: rtl8723bs v4.3.5.5_12290.20140916_BTCOEX20140507-4E40
[    8.092673] RTL8723BS: rtl8723bs BT-Coex version = BTCOEX20140507-4E40
[    8.303955] RTL8723BS: rtw_ndev_init(wlan0)
[    8.304653] RTL8723BS: module init ret =0
[   13.200223] rtl8723bs: acquire FW from file:rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin
[   17.832536] RTL8723BS: rtw_set_802_11_connect(wlan0)  fw_state = 0x00000008
[   17.889893] RTL8723BS: start auth
[   17.892815] RTL8723BS: auth success, start assoc
[   17.901012] RTL8723BS: rtw_cfg80211_indicate_connect(wlan0) BSS not found !!
[   17.901053] RTL8723BS: assoc success
[   17.913846] RTL8723BS: send eapol packet
[   17.939873] RTL8723BS: send eapol packet
[   17.942652] RTL8723BS: set pairwise key camid:4, addr:50:c7:bf:31:a1:fa, kid:0, type:AES
[   17.944712] RTL8723BS: set group key camid:5, addr:50:c7:bf:31:a1:fa, kid:1, type:TKIP
$ rfkill list all
0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

**UPD:**

After boot and login to GUI

```
$ dmesg | grep -i blue
$ sudo lsmod | grep btrtl
$ sudo lsmod | grep btqca
$ sudo lsmod | grep btintel
$ sudo lsmod | grep hci_uart
$ sudo lsmod | grep bnep
$ sudo lsmod | grep hidp
$ sudo lsmod | grep btbcm
$ sudo lsmod | grep rfcomm
$
```

i.e. all those commands return nothing,so

```
$ sudo modprobe btrtl
$ sudo modprobe btqca
$ sudo modprobe btintel
$ sudo modprobe hci_uart
$ sudo modprobe bnep
$ sudo modprobe hidp
$ sudo modprobe btbcm
$ sudo modprobe rfcomm
```

then

```
$ dmesg | grep -i blue
[  922.885915] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  922.886059] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  922.886083] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  922.886097] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  922.886125] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 1110.038155] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[ 1110.038159] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[ 1110.038161] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[ 1110.038237] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[ 1110.038240] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[ 1110.038317] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[ 1110.038469] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[ 1110.038756] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[ 1110.038823] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[ 1110.038825] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[ 1110.038892] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[ 1127.857569] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 1127.857580] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 1127.857594] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 1135.830750] Bluetooth: HIDP (Human Interface Emulation) ver 1.2
[ 1135.830767] Bluetooth: HIDP socket layer initialized
[ 1153.832918] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[ 1153.832949] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[ 1153.832979] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

and

```
$ sudo lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
rfcomm                 81920  0
hidp                   28672  0
bnep                   24576  0
hci_uart              126976  0
btbcm                  16384  1 hci_uart
btintel                24576  1 hci_uart
btqca                  20480  1 hci_uart
btrtl                  24576  1 hci_uart
bluetooth             581632  10 btrtl,hidp,btqca,btintel,hci_uart,btbcm,bnep,rfcomm
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
ecc                    28672  1 ecdh_generic
snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5640    40960  2
snd_hdmi_lpe_audio     28672  1
mei_hdcp               24576  0
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
gpio_keys              20480  0
intel_soc_dts_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
coretemp               20480  0
kvm_intel             286720  0
kvm                   663552  1 kvm_intel
punit_atom_debug       16384  0
nls_iso8859_1          16384  2
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
aesni_intel           372736  0
crypto_simd            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 24576  2 crypto_simd,ghash_clmulni_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
snd_sof_acpi           20480  0
snd_sof_intel_byt      20480  1 snd_sof_acpi
snd_sof_intel_ipc      20480  1 snd_sof_intel_byt
snd_sof               106496  3 snd_sof_acpi,snd_sof_intel_byt,snd_sof_intel_ipc
snd_sof_xtensa_dsp     16384  1 snd_sof_acpi
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_sof
r8723bs               573440  0
snd_soc_rt5670        155648  0
joydev                 24576  0
snd_intel_sst_acpi     20480  1
snd_soc_rt5651        102400  0
snd_intel_sst_core     61440  1 snd_intel_sst_acpi
input_leds             16384  0
snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform   110592  2 snd_intel_sst_core
snd_soc_rt5645        172032  0
cfg80211              704512  1 r8723bs
mac_hid                16384  0
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match    32768  2 snd_sof_acpi,snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_soc_rt5640        143360  2 snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5640
snd_soc_acpi           16384  4 snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5640,snd_sof_acpi,snd_soc_acpi_intel_match,snd_intel_sst_acpi
snd_soc_rl6231         20480  4 snd_soc_rt5651,snd_soc_rt5670,snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_rt5645
i915                 1986560  14
snd_soc_core          245760  7 snd_soc_rt5651,snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5640,snd_sof,snd_soc_rt5670,snd_soc_rt5640,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_soc_rt5645
snd_compress           24576  1 snd_soc_core
ac97_bus               16384  1 snd_soc_core
snd_pcm_dmaengine      16384  1 snd_soc_core
hid_multitouch         28672  0
snd_pcm               106496  10 snd_soc_rt5651,snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5640,snd_sof,snd_soc_rt5670,snd_soc_rt5640,snd_hdmi_lpe_audio,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_soc_core,snd_soc_rt5645,snd_pcm_dmaengine
ak8975                 24576  0
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 i915
acer_wmi               24576  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 acer_wmi
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
mei_txe                28672  1
wmi_bmof               16384  0
mei                   106496  3 mei_hdcp,mei_txe
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
processor_thermal_device    24576  0
inv_mpu6050_i2c        16384  0
intel_rapl_common      24576  2 intel_rapl_msr,processor_thermal_device
inv_mpu6050            28672  2 inv_mpu6050_i2c
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
intel_soc_dts_iosf     20480  2 intel_soc_dts_thermal,processor_thermal_device
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  2 inv_mpu6050,ak8975
int3400_thermal        20480  0
kfifo_buf              16384  1 industrialio_triggered_buffer
acpi_thermal_rel       16384  1 int3400_thermal
soc_button_array       20480  0
int3403_thermal        16384  0
int340x_thermal_zone    16384  2 int3403_thermal,processor_thermal_device
int3406_thermal        16384  0
i2c_mux                16384  1 inv_mpu6050_i2c
dptf_power             16384  0
industrialio           73728  4 industrialio_triggered_buffer,inv_mpu6050,kfifo_buf,ak8975
snd                    90112  16 snd_seq,snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5640,snd_seq_device,snd_timer,snd_compress,snd_hdmi_lpe_audio,snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
intel_int0002_vgpio    16384  1
acpi_pad              184320  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
8250_dw                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  5
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
drm                   491520  8 drm_kms_helper,i915
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
hid_ite                16384  0
hid_generic            16384  0
mmc_block              49152  5
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
usbhid                 57344  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
wmi                    32768  2 acer_wmi,wmi_bmof
video                  49152  3 acer_wmi,int3406_thermal,i915
dw_dmac                16384  0
dw_dmac_core           28672  1 dw_dmac
i2c_hid                28672  0
hid                   131072  6 i2c_hid,hidp,hid_ite,usbhid,hid_multitouch,hid_generic
sdhci_acpi             24576  0
sdhci                  65536  1 sdhci_acpi
```

but when I try to switch BT on in settings dialog the switch becomes blue, but nothing happens, that is BT still does not work.

**UPD 2020-11-28**

I tried kernel upgrade, now I am on 5.8.0-25-generic, but that did not help.

```
$ dmesg | egrep -i -e "8723|blue|rfcomm|hci|mmc|rtl"
[    0.126698] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] at [mem 0xe0000000-0xe3ffffff] (base 0xe0000000)
[    0.126698] PCI: not using MMCONFIG
[    0.220530] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] at [mem 0xe0000000-0xe3ffffff] (base 0xe0000000)
[    0.230809] [Firmware Info]: PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xe0000000-0xe3ffffff] not reserved in ACPI motherboard resources
[    0.230814] PCI: not using MMCONFIG
[    0.281489] acpi PNP0A08:00: fail to add MMCONFIG information, can't access extended PCI configuration space under this bridge.
[    1.215434] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.215452] ehci-pci: EHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.215483] ehci-platform: EHCI generic platform driver
[    1.215544] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.215552] ohci-pci: OHCI PCI platform driver
[    1.215584] ohci-platform: OHCI generic platform driver
[    1.215618] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    3.735915] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    3.735917] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    3.742860] mmc0: SDHCI controller on ACPI [INT33BB:00] using ADMA
[    3.768137] mmc1: SDHCI controller on ACPI [80860F14:00] using ADMA
[    3.788409] mmc2: SDHCI controller on ACPI [80860F14:01] using ADMA
[    3.792645] mmc0: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    3.847968] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    3.847986] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    3.849090] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: hcc params 0x200077c1 hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000000000009810
[    3.849098] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: cache line size of 64 is not supported
[    3.849712] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    3.849715] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.8.0-25-generic xhci-hcd
[    3.875942] mmc2: Problem switching card into high-speed mode!
[    3.876070] mmc2: new SDHC card at address 0001
[    3.940300] mmc1: new HS200 MMC card at address 0001
[    3.977460] mmcblk2: mmc2:0001 SPCC 14.6 GiB 
[    3.980124]  mmcblk2: p1
[    3.981199] mmcblk1: mmc1:0001 CWBC3R 58.2 GiB 
[    3.981516] mmcblk1boot0: mmc1:0001 CWBC3R partition 1 4.00 MiB
[    3.981845] mmcblk1boot1: mmc1:0001 CWBC3R partition 2 4.00 MiB
[    3.982051] mmcblk1rpmb: mmc1:0001 CWBC3R partition 3 4.00 MiB, chardev (240:0)
[    3.986302]  mmcblk1: p1 p2
[    4.395717] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    4.395745] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    4.395768] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    4.396312] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    4.396321] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.8.0-25-generic xhci-hcd
[    4.593186] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    4.734185] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    5.182221] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    5.714516] EXT4-fs (mmcblk1p2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    7.584890] r8723bs: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    7.620644] RTL8723BS: module init start
[    7.620649] RTL8723BS: rtl8723bs v4.3.5.5_12290.20140916_BTCOEX20140507-4E40
[    7.620650] RTL8723BS: rtl8723bs BT-Coex version = BTCOEX20140507-4E40
[    7.937449] RTL8723BS: rtw_ndev_init(wlan0)
[    7.950610] RTL8723BS: module init ret =0
[    8.663080] Modules linked in: snd_hdmi_lpe_audio(+) hid_ite(+) snd_soc_sst_bytcr_rt5640(+) mei_hdcp gpio_keys intel_rapl_msr intel_soc_dts_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm punit_atom_debug crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel crypto_simd cryptd glue_helper intel_cstate joydev mac_hid efi_pstore r8723bs(CE) snd_soc_rt5670 snd_soc_rt5651 cfg80211 snd_soc_rt5645 snd_intel_sst_acpi snd_intel_sst_core ak8975 snd_soc_sst_atom_hifi2_platform snd_soc_rt5640 usbhid snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_rl6231 snd_soc_acpi snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus i915 hid_multitouch snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_pcm drm_kms_helper cec acer_wmi rc_core snd_seq_midi sparse_keymap i2c_algo_bit wmi_bmof fb_sys_fops snd_seq_midi_event syscopyarea sysfillrect mei_txe sysimgblt snd_rawmidi mei snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer dptf_power soc_button_array int3406_thermal processor_thermal_device intel_rapl_common int3403_thermal inv_mpu6050_i2c intel_soc_dts_iosf int3400_thermal int340x_thermal_zone
[    8.663135]  inv_mpu6050 atomisp_ov2722(CE) atomisp_gmin_platform(CE) acpi_thermal_rel videodev industrialio_triggered_buffer intel_int0002_vgpio snd kfifo_buf cm32181 i2c_mux industrialio acpi_pad mc soundcore 8250_dw sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic mmc_block crc32_pclmul lpc_ich xhci_pci xhci_pci_renesas video wmi dw_dmac dw_dmac_core i2c_hid hid sdhci_acpi sdhci
[   11.975496] mmc2: Problem switching card into high-speed mode!
[   14.284231] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   14.284282] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   14.284293] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   14.284297] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   14.284307] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   15.914839] rtl8723bs: acquire FW from file:rtlwifi/rtl8723bs_nic.bin
[   18.437803] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   18.437806] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   18.437816] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   20.111345] RTL8723BS: rtw_set_802_11_connect(wlan0)  fw_state = 0x00000008
[   20.192610] RTL8723BS: start auth
[   20.197563] RTL8723BS: auth success, start assoc
[   20.204229] RTL8723BS: rtw_cfg80211_indicate_connect(wlan0) BSS not found !!
[   20.204257] RTL8723BS: assoc success
[   20.209185] RTL8723BS: send eapol packet
[   20.221098] RTL8723BS: send eapol packet
[   20.221260] RTL8723BS: set pairwise key camid:4, addr:50:c7:bf:31:a1:fa, kid:0, type:AES
[   20.225943] RTL8723BS: set group key camid:5, addr:50:c7:bf:31:a1:fa, kid:1, type:TKIP
[   68.474482] mmc2: Problem switching card into high-speed mode!
[   68.482849] FAT-fs (mmcblk2p1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
[   73.703696] mmc2: Problem switching card into high-speed mode!
```

but

```
$ sudo bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# exit
$
```

Looks like I'm missing something, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: Hi! I have the same laptop. Acer Switch 10. Did you manage to enable the bluetooth? Also, can you change screen brightness? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately, not yet, see the update. I can move the brightness slider, but it has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth is fully working on the rtl8723bs since the 4.19 kernel.  It is working on my Xubuntu 20.04 upgrade on that hardware. Necessary firmware is present in default installs, no compiles needed.  Look at the modules loaded, and check the "bluetooth" line.  It should have btrtl, btqca, btintel, hci_uart, bnep, hidp, btbcm, and rfcomm.  The last three may be missing, and cause your problem.  Load them manually:

```
sudo modprobe hidp
sudo modprobe btbcm
sudo modprobe rfcomm
```

to see if that allow Bluetooth to function.
Older instructions on compiles may be referring to the Intel (?) version (supplied on Ubuntu 14.04) with the firmware built in.  That is not the version supplied which works, but needs the firmware loaded separately.  Your listed firmware is the correct version.

Comment: Thank you, I updated the question with the modules, but unfortunately, BT still does not work. Maybe something else is missing. It is strange that during the boot nothing BT-related is loaded.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? I'm also having issues with the Bluetooth on my Acer.

Comment: @DariusP You should ask your own question and supply your hardware details, but I have noticed some trouble with the 5.6 and 5.7 kernels seeing bluetooth on hardware which the 4.19 kernel still sees it perfectly. No longer have the Xubuntu to try out but not doing anything about it since don't  use BT anymore on that hardware (Intel Compute Stick with Ubuntu 14.04, Antix 19, and Debian 10).